Jnetpcap library did not identify Memcache Protocol packets as TCP packet
I am trying to collect the details such as source ip, destination ip, memcache command, memcache key, memcache value, response to memcache command, etc from Memcache protocol packets.
The pcap file was collected by running the memecache server and the client on localhost i.e. packets were collected on device 'lo0'.
When the following code was run to print the details of the Memcache Protocol packets, it did not identify any of the packets collected as TCP packets and print the details.
Code:
public class Example1_CapturePacketsAndPrintHeaders {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the example.
     *
     * @param args ignored
     * @throws PcapException any pcap exceptions
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws PcapException {
        new Example1_CapturePacketsAndPrintHeaders().main();
    }

    void main() {

        /* Pcap capture file to read included with the example JAR file */
        final String PCAP_FILE = "/work/captured_packets.pcap";

        /*
         * Automatically close Pcap resource when done and checks the client and
         * installed runtime API versions to ensure they are compatible.
         */
        try (NetPcap pcap = NetPcap.openOffline(PCAP_FILE)) {

            /* Set a pretty print formatter to toString() method */
            pcap.setPacketFormatter(new PacketFormat())
                    .setDescriptorType(PacketDescriptorType.TYPE2);

            /* Number of packets to capture */
            final int PACKET_COUNT = 14;

            /* Pro API! Create protocol headers and reuse inside the dispatch handler */
            final Ethernet ethernet = new Ethernet();
            final Ip4 ip4 = new Ip4();
            final Ip6 ip6 = new Ip6();
            final Tcp tcp = new Tcp();
            final Ip4tRouterAlertOption router = new Ip4tRouterAlertOption();

            /* Capture packets and access protocol headers */
            pcap.dispatch(PACKET_COUNT, (String user, Packet packet) -> { // Pro API

                
                // If present, printout ethernet header
                if (packet.hasHeader(ethernet))
                    System.out.println(ethernet);

                // If present, printout ip4 header
                if (packet.hasHeader(ip4))
                    System.out.println(ip4);

                // If present, printout ip6 header
                if (packet.hasHeader(ip6))
                    System.out.println(ip6);

                // If present, printout IPv4.router header extension
                if (packet.hasHeader(ip4) && ip4.hasOption(router))
                    System.out.println(router);

                // If present, printout tcp header
                if (packet.hasHeader(tcp)) {
                    System.out.println(tcp);
                }

                String sk = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(packet.buffer()).toString();

                if (sk.contains("VALUE")) {
                    System.out.println(sk.substring(sk.indexOf("VALUE")));
                }
                if (sk.contains("set")) {
                    System.out.println(sk.substring(sk.indexOf("set")));
                }
                if (sk.contains("get")) {
                    System.out.println(sk.substring(sk.indexOf("get")));
                }
            }, "Example1 - Hello World");
        } catch (PcapException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}


Wireshark screenshot of packets collected in the pcap file:
Wireshark_Screenshot_pcap
Output of the code:
get qwe

VALUE qwe 0 3
ewq
END

set key 0 0 3

get key

VALUE key 0 3
asd
END


Process finished with exit code 0

Please help me understand what am I doing wrong? Let me know if any further details are needed. Thank you!
I was only partly successful in getting some data using the following code snippet.
                String sk = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(packet.buffer()).toString();

                if (sk.contains("VALUE")) {
                    System.out.println(sk.substring(sk.indexOf("VALUE")));
                }
                if (sk.contains("set")) {
                    System.out.println(sk.substring(sk.indexOf("set")));
                }
                if (sk.contains("get")) {
                    System.out.println(sk.substring(sk.indexOf("get")));
                }

